# "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a winforms project which has `formA` and `formB`. When `formA` loads, it calls class `Calculation` to do some logic and opens `formB` to display something. `formA` has a button to close `formB`. When I click the button to close `formB`, it give me an error:

> "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'formB' accessed from a
>   thread other than the thread it was created on."

```
List<Form> forms = new List<Form>();

formA_Load()
{
    DemoObject calfrmA = new DemoObject();
    calfrmA.getData();
}


public class DemoObject
{
    public void getData()
    {
         formB frmB = new frmB();
         frmB.Name = "frmB";
         forms.Add(frmB);
         frmB.Show();
    }
}
```

`formA` button click

```
public void button1_click()
{
       foreach(Form frm in forms)
       {
            if(frm.Name == "frmB")
            {
                 frm.Close();
            }
       }
}
```

the `frm.Close()` gives an error. How I can fix the issue? Please guide me.  Thanks

**Edited code**: I have tried but still the same. `DemoObject` is a class.

```
formA_Load()
{
    foreach (DemoObject tobject in objectList.Values) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(delegate ()
                {
                    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                    {
                        tobject.getData();
                    }));
                });
                thread.Start();
            }
}
```

Comment: Never create a Form object on a worker thread.  If you don't know how to debug this problem then you will definitely not know how to [do this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/).  Set a breakpoint on the getData() method, when it breaks use Debug > Windows > Threads to find out how that happened.

Comment: Show us your code where you create the `Task` or `Thread`.

Comment: Check if there is some work that you do on form close / closing / hide etc. If not, provide us with reproducible example. At least show us the way you create threads/tasks and forms. Do you create forms in another thread?

Comment: The above code is how I open form B and how I close the form B after open it up.

Comment: A [mcve] is what we need.

Comment: I have create a small project to simulate the problem but I can't reproduced the same problem.  The project have Form A and Form B and class DemoObject.  In form A have a open button and close button.  When click the open button, it will initiate class DemoObject and call to getData function.  The getData function will open form B.  When click close button in Form A, it able to close the opened Form B.  No such error occur.  Headache now

Comment: It's pointless to start threads that do nothing but schedule work to run on the UI thread and then wait for it to finish.